# disable listview overscroll on samsung android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I need to totally disable overscroll in my listviews so I can implement my own overscroll functionality.

Seems to be simple enough when looking at the core listview classes, just by setting the overscroll mode to OVERSCROLL_NEVER. This doesn't do anything on my Samsung Galaxy s2. I have also tried to overwrite the overScrollBy function to do nothing. That doesn't work either.

Has anyone had much experience with samsung ListView customizations that can help me?

Comment: You don't have to worry anymore, Samsung have totally disabled the overscroll in their 2.3.5+ updates (even Android's API9 overScrollBy() function)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261911/samsung-galaxy-s2-2-3-5-not-calling-overscrollby

Comment: and enabled it back in 2.3.6 . didn't last long...

Comment: awesome... #@$#%!^$@^@^$@

Answer (score 1):

Try this setOverScrollMode (int mode).. check this link out:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode(int)

Comment: Ok darn. I'm using API 7, so it does not have this method. :(

Answer (score 1):

Not my solution but check out https://gist.github.com/DHuckaby/3919939. Works for me. Stupid Samsung

Answer (score 0):

How about below code:

```
@Override
protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0.0f;
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Answer inspired from @cdhabecker [Android ScrollView fading edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889908/android-scrollview-fading-edge)

Answer (score 0):

New [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) can be used instead of `ListView` to tackle the problem.