# Android Header and Footer highlights when hit top or bottom of list

Tags: android, listview

Is there a way to not let this happen? It's quite ugly aesthetically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Force setting a background color to the list item solves the highlighting issue.

Answer (score 1):

*That's not a bug. That's a feature!*

If you want to disable it, try calling:

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

Unfortunately, it apparently doesn't work on all devices. (See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563904/disable-listview-overscroll-on-samsung-android).)

Comment: Ok darn. I'm using API 7, so it does not have this method. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add one of these attributes to your list view in your layout file.

```
<ListView 
  android:overScrollHeader="@null" 
  android:overScrollFooter="@null" />
```

or

```
<ListView android:overScrollMode="never" />
```